# ORACLE merge two SELECTs with UNION adding up

Tags: sql, oracle, select, union

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT 
c.customer_code,                           
SUM(units) AS tot_units,
SUM(total_amount) AS tot_money,
null as units_to_date,
null as amount_to_date,
FROM customers c
join transactions t on t.customer_code = c.customer_code
WHERE customer_active='S'
GROUP BY c.customer_code
UNION
SELECT 
c.customer_code,               
null AS tot_units,
null AS tot_money,
SUM(units) as units_to_date,
SUM(total_amount) as amount_to_date, 
FROM customers c
join transactions t on t.customer_code = c.customer_code
WHERE customer_active='S' and t.transaction_date >= (trunc(current_date) - (60 * INTERVAL '1' DAY))
GROUP BY c.customer_code;
```

The result is:

```
CUSTOMER_CODE, TOT_UNITS, TOT_AMOUNT, TO_DATE_UNITS, TO_DATE_AMOUNT
0000001        450        300         null           null          
0000001        null       null        30             15
```

and I need the result to be :

```
CUSTOMER_CODE, TOT_UNITS, TOT_AMOUNT, TO_DATE_UNITS, TO_DATE_AMOUNT
0000001        450        300         30             15
```

I've tried with UNION but it doesn't work.

Comment: But why are you shouting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending @VJHil's answer, it *is* possible to get rid of the `union`. The trick is to filter out everything outside of you desired date range using `case`:

```
SELECT   c.customer_code,
         SUM (units) AS tot_units,
         SUM (total_amount) AS tot_money,
         SUM (
            CASE
               WHEN t.transaction_date >=
                       (TRUNC (CURRENT_DATE) - (60 * INTERVAL '1' DAY)) THEN
                  units
               ELSE
                  NULL
            END)
            AS units_to_date,
         SUM (
            CASE
               WHEN t.transaction_date >=
                       (TRUNC (CURRENT_DATE) - (60 * INTERVAL '1' DAY)) THEN
                  total_amount
               ELSE
                  NULL
            END)
            AS amount_to_date
FROM     customers c JOIN transactions t ON t.customer_code = c.customer_code
WHERE    customer_active = 'S'
GROUP BY c.customer_code
```

This should perform better than any solution where you access the data twice.

Comment: I agree with your approach and you are "faithful" to his original conditions regarding summing units_to_date and ammount_to_date.  Of course, summing NULLS will result in NULLS. Thus I think this is technically right, but I think an end user would want zeros in lieu of NULLS.

Comment: @Patrick: I tend to use `null` rather than zero in this kind of scenario because it works with both `sum` and `count`, so it's a little more utilitarian. If a non-null result is wanted when the column is empty, `nvl` or `coalesce` could be used to convert it.

Answer (score 2):

May be split up as two views and join them.
Then either Use `NVL()` or `MAX()` which ever suits best.

```
WITH V1 AS (
SELECT 
c.customer_code,                           
SUM(units) AS tot_units,
SUM(total_amount) AS tot_money,
null as units_to_date,
null as amount_to_date,
FROM customers c
join transactions t on t.customer_code = c.customer_code
WHERE customer_active='S'
GROUP BY c.customer_code
),
V2 AS (
SELECT 
c.customer_code,               
null AS tot_units,
null AS tot_money,
SUM(units) as units_to_date,
SUM(total_amount) as amount_to_date, 
FROM customers c
join transactions t on t.customer_code = c.customer_code
WHERE customer_active='S' and t.transaction_date >= (trunc(current_date) - (60 * INTERVAL '1' DAY))
GROUP BY c.customer_code)
SELECT 
 V1.CUSTOMER_CODE, NVL(V1.TOT_UNITS,V2. TOT_UNITS), NVL(V1.TOT_AMOUNT,V2. TOT_AMOUNT), NVL(V1.TO_DATE_UNITS,V2. TO_DATE_UNITS) TO_DATE_AMOUNT
FROM V1, V2
WHERE V1.CUSTOMER_CODE = V2.CUSTOMER_CODE
```

Comment: Futher testing this solution i found that when V2 get no records (because there are not purchases within the time interval) i get no records as result. i will try with an outer join.

Comment: Fine, you might also consider Allan's answer, as it sounds better to me! Unless your Table is Not very big.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason for you to use union. Try this, I just removed nulls.

```
SELECT 
c.customer_code,               
SUM(units) AS tot_units,
SUM(total_amount) AS tot_money,
SUM(units) as units_to_date,
SUM(total_amount) as amount_to_date, 
MIN(transaction_date) AS first_transaction_date
FROM customers c
join transactions t on t.customer_code = c.customer_code
WHERE customer_active='S' and t.transaction_date >= (trunc(current_date) - (60 * INTERVAL '1' DAY))
GROUP BY c.customer_code;
```

Comment: Hello . Thanks but in total_amount i need the total_amount purchased by that client regardinless the date of purchase, and in amount_to_date i need only the amount purchased within a time interval.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution;

```
WITH CUSTOMER AS (
  SELECT C.CUSTOMER_CODE,
         SUM(UNITS) AS TOT_UNITS,
         SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) AS TOT_MONEY,
         NULL AS UNITS_TO_DATE,
         NULL AS AMOUNT_TO_DATE,
    FROM CUSTOMERS C JOIN TRANSACTIONS T ON T.CUSTOMER_CODE = C.CUSTOMER_CODE
   WHERE CUSTOMER_ACTIVE = 'S'
GROUP BY C.CUSTOMER_CODE
UNION
  SELECT C.CUSTOMER_CODE,
         NULL AS TOT_UNITS,
         NULL AS TOT_MONEY,
         SUM(UNITS) AS UNITS_TO_DATE,
         SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT_TO_DATE,
    FROM CUSTOMERS C JOIN TRANSACTIONS T ON T.CUSTOMER_CODE = C.CUSTOMER_CODE
   WHERE     CUSTOMER_ACTIVE = 'S'
         AND T.TRANSACTION_DATE >= (TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) - (60 * INTERVAL '1' DAY))
GROUP BY C.CUSTOMER_CODE)
    SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE,
           MAX(TOT_UNITS) AS TOT_UNITS,
           MAX(TOT_MONEY) AS TOT_MONEY,
           MAX(UNITS_TO_DATE) AS UNITS_TO_DATE,
           MAX(AMOUNT_TO_DATE) AS AMOUNT_TO_DATE
      FROM CUSTOMER
  GROUP BY CUSTOMER_CODE
```